# Content sniffing XSS vulnerable browsers

Tags: web-application, xss

In order to prevent [Cross-site scripting (XSS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) in a private web application that supports image upload, I intend to reject browsers that are vulnerable to content sniffing.

Which browsers are currently vulnerable to this exploit?

PS. I'm aware of the `X-Content-Type-Options` header, which isn't fully supported as far as I know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't send a content-type header most browsers will do content sniffing. If you do send a content-type header as far as I know all versions of internet explorer will do sniffing unless `x-content-type-options: nosniff` is set. IE should accept this header starting with IE8 (blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/02/ie8-security-part-vi-beta-2-update.aspx).

Just an idea: you might try to detect if the browser is vulnerable to content-type sniffing by serving an HTML page with an redirect as `content-type: text/plain`. If you the browser gets redirected it is vulnerable (you might also check the effectiveness of the nosniff option this way). If you just include this test-page into a small and maybe invisible iframe you can do the check without affecting the rest of the website.

Comment: Hmm capability testing is a nice approach, I think it would work with single page js applications, so I could check whether the browser is vulnerable to content sniffing and prevent the inclusion of images if necessary... I will combine this with a server side image resizer, that should do the trick.

Comment: @Staffen Ullrich: How to test browser is vulnerable with simple HTML page? I didn't quiet get that. Can you post an example please?

Comment: @ParagJ: `<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/vulnerable.html"></head></html>`. Serve without content-type. Only if the browser interprets this as HTML it will issue the redirect.